# How to visit php file in my custom directory under site root directory

Tags: directory, configuration

I hope to create a directory `wp-mybiz` as same level as `wp-content`, `wp-admin`, and `wp-includes` under site root directory to collect my business logic codes.

But if I try to visit php using url `http://example.com/site/wp-mybiz/mycode.php`, it get **raw php** file rather than html file generated by this php.

Any wrong to configure apache, wordpress, or php?

Comment: what content you have written to that PHP. Have you added any header() to that PHP?

Comment: "to collect my business logic codes" - I think you'd normally put these in your theme, or in a plugin specific to your site. What sort of function are you adding, and are you changing the WP core files?

Comment: If you use WordPress then embrace it.  It's always best to do things the WordPress way (same for any framework). As @Rup says, put your code into a plugin or theme.

Answer (score 1):

Only Apache is "responsible for caring" that your script is PHP. AFAIK, whether you need to use AddHandler or AddType depends on whether your PHP is installed as a module or as CGI. You can try creating .htaccess in wp-mybiz/ folder containg some of the common solutions/workarounds

1) **AddType application/x-httpd-php .php**

2a) **AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php**
2b) **AddHandler x-httpd-php .php**

or a combination of both.

To help isolate the real issue clear your cache and get the headers (i.e. via 'Live HTTP Headers" or similar).

**Edit**: Excellent thread - https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4557229.htm